# How to rename property/attribute of resource with jsonapi-resources ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonapi-resources

I am building json api with rails using [jsonapi-resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) gem. The library is really great, it does a lot of job.

However some column names in our DB is not really meaninful to be showed in API.

So, my question: is possible to rename property/attribute in resource?

Example:

Let's say I have model User with attribute `login`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :login
end
```

And I want `login` in API appear as `username`, e.g.:

```
class UserResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attribute :username, map_to: :login
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does setting an [alias](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute) for the attribute work? Then if you specify `attribute :username` in JR it should pull the value from `:login`.

Comment: @Alexander Can you put your answer to the answers? It works, and seems to be the best option among other aliases, because it also works nice with search.

Comment: Sure! Glad to know it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `:username` [alias](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute) for your `:login` attribute:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :login

  alias_attribute :username, :login
end
```

Then in `JSONAPI::Resources` (JR) you can specify your `username` attribute like so:

```
class UserResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attribute :username
end
```

By setting an alias, you've mapped the `username` attribute to the `login` attribute, so it doesn't matter whether you use `username` or `login`, it will return the same value.

Comment: Thanks! That is not 100% pure solutation (the most preferable would be to not touch the model, only resource), but still it works the best among othe alias options, because it does not breaking filtering (search) feature.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use alias or alias_method.  http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/01/08/alias-vs-alias-method.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the easiest way to change attribute name or value is to re-define the attribute. In your case it would be:

```
attributes :username

def username
  @model.login
end
```

Here it is in the Readme: https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources#formatting

Comment: Thanks! But, won't work properly for filtering (search)